# losing cookie while requesting from subdomain to other subdomain

Tags: express, next.js, cookies, https, request

Currently I'm struggling with odd phenomenon about losing cookie..

Previously, I used AWS as my infra to handle frontend and backend as well.

[previous scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tl8a.png)

Due to deployment issue, (frontend deployment sequence took too long) decided to use Vercel for frontend.

[current scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iVhH.png)

Whats happening now, is that request started not to append cookie on request header.

Since I'm currently developing  streaming service,

I have 3 actors for streaming scenario

I'll abbreviate as (a.domain.com , b.domain.com, c.domain.com)

`a.domain.com = frontend b.domain.com = backend c.domain.com = dvd server`

below is my scenario

[streaming scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zC8c.png)

Looking at inspection table of cookie (chrome inspection tool->application tab), it seems that `set-cookie` works well.

[set cookie works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Elw.png)

but while making request to "c.domain.com" I'm finding that cookie is lost on request header.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsTmo.png)

What I've tried??

1. set
   `credential : 'include'`
   while fetching :: frontend
2. allow CORS :: backend
3. add `Domain` attribute while setting cookie :: backend
   (ex.
   `Set-Cookie: wwwCookie=wwwCookie; Domain=.domain.com`) <- not sure is it
   `Domain=domain.com`)

P.S

While comparing with previous request and current request(which fail)

I've found that `partition key` is added for current request. Does this relates to current issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

The problem was coming from AWS API Gateway configuration.

I've needed to set CORS configuration of API Gateway service exactly same as my server configuration setting.

Followed following article

https://medium.com/@sharadokey/understanding-cors-and-cross-origin-cookies-bf36d624da78

Sending Thanks to Sharadokey